# Можно ли сложение двух массивов переделать в Stream Api?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, лямбда-выражение

**Имеется 2 массива:**

```
ArrayList<Double>arrayList1;
ArrayList<Double>arrayList2;
```

Подскажите, как можно сложить эти массивы, используя Java 8 Stream Api?

Например:

```
arraylist1: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 
arraylist2: 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 
результат:  5.0, 7.0, 9.0
```

Comment: что есть сложение двух массивов? и да....ArrayList — это НЕ массив

Comment: Сложить 2 Array длины первого листа

Comment: А если по-русски написать, а не загадками? И причем тут тогда arrayList2?

Comment: Блиииин у arrayList1 и arrayList2 одинаковой размерностью! Я хочу их сложить как будто это два массива! Как ещё блин написать?

Comment: Так в ответе же всё написано. сам убедись написав `System.out.println(result.collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Это же конкатенация строк. Например arraylist1 - 1.0 , 2.0, 3.0 а во втором 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 то ответ в вашем способе будет по идее 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 . А должно быть: 5.0, 7.0, 9.0

Comment: ну вот видишь, не прошло и суток как ты смог наконец-то хоть какой-то пример показать того, что ты называешь сложением массивов. Вот скажи, как прочитав твой вопрос можно было об этом догадаться? как? А еще вопрос - а если в одном 10 элементов, а в другом 3 - то какой результат ты ожидаешь?

Comment: Там всегда равное количество элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Stream API Java8 нет такой простой функции как zip (как, например, в Python). Приходится писать ее ручками:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Zipper
{
    static List<Double> arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    static List<Double> arrayList2 = Arrays.asList(4.0,5.0,6.0);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(
            IntStream.range(0, Math.min(arrayList1.size(), arrayList2.size()))
                     .mapToDouble(i -> arrayList1.get(i) + arrayList2.get(i))
                     .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Double>(),
                          (c, e) -> c.add(e),
                        (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2))
                     .toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Для объединения стримов есть метод-хелпер Stream.concat:

```
Stream<Double> result = Stream.concat(arrayList1.stream(), arrayList2.stream());
```

Comment: Вы вопрос читали? Мне нужно сложение двух массивов!!!

Comment: @Санаев да, читал, исходя из присутствия в нем stream api сложно предположить, что вам нужно что-то другое.

Comment: То есть элемент первого листа сложить с элементом 2листа

Comment: @Санаев etki вам и предлагает **сложение массивов**. А то что вы хотите — это попарное сложение элементов из двух массивов. Другой пример: строка это почти что массив символов. Строка `"два"` плюс строка `"три"` равняется `"дватри"`, но никак не `"пять"`.